# Extract additional NSString from array of JSON parsing data for TableView

Tags: objective-c, json

I'm parsing my json file and showing it in a grouped table view.

```
-(void) connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
    NSDictionary *allDataDictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:webData options:0 error:nil];
    NSDictionary *parks = [allDataDictionary objectForKey:@"Parks"];
    NSArray *arrayOfParks = [parks objectForKey:@"Park"];

    for (NSDictionary *diction in arrayOfParks) {
        NSString *hebName = [diction objectForKey:@"hebName"];

        NSString *engName = [diction objectForKey:@"engName"];
        NSString *latitude = [diction objectForKey:@"lat"];
        NSString *longtitude = [diction objectForKey:@"long"];

        [array addObject:hebName];
    }
    [[self myTableView] reloadData];
}

-(void)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSString *details = [array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"B7Tour" message:details delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil] show];
}
```

It works very well and I present in my table view the `engName`.
Clicking on the item at the table view will pop up an alert with the engName `itself`.

My question is: how to extract the particular `latitude` and `longtitude` and save them?
I know how to present them in the table view but I want to extract and save them for additional usage.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to have the array of dictionaries exist outside this method. 
Then you can access them any time. 
Then you can maintain another ivar that is your current selection in the table view.
From there it is pretty straight forward to call the objectForKey: on the currently selected object.

Comment: thats what i thought to do, i just thought there is much simple way.